# heap Limit in a Folder hierarchy

Tags: directory, io, heap-memory, limit

I have for example 
Folder(1) ->Folder(2)->.....Folder(x)

within each Folder there some files.

I need to preform Encryption OR Decryption ...
I have a Looping/ recursion functions to go over all files and folders, to perform the Ciphering... also read/write files.

all this consumes Memory .. Right now I have a Heap of limit = 20.

I would like to know the OPTIMAL way to select my HEAP limit.

I know this is not related but just in case I'm using C#.NET

Comment: Please re-phrase your question; I cannot understand what you're trying to accomplish or what your question to us is. Thanks.

Comment: If your code is written to be recursive, you'll need a fixed amount of heap space but your stack may need to grow significantly to handle the depth. If your code is iterative, you'll probably need a fixed amount of heap and stack both -- and the amount you'll need _may_ vary from system to system or run to run, based on the contents of the drive. (Large directories _may_ require more memory to store the directory listing and which files you've handled.) But why are you _setting_ a heap limit? Why not let the runtime environment give you what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled Exceptions using try-catch ... rather than defining a heap limit which should differ from one machine to another, worked fine for me.